# File download link in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, download, activeadmin

How do I create a file download link in ActiveAdmin to download an uploaded file?

I tried something like this:

```
action_item :only=> :show do
 link_to('Download file', [@user, :upload_file])
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The `action_item` will establish the button in the taskbar, but it does not create the actual route or the controller's action method.

You can achieve the download functionality by creating a custom member_action in `user.rb`

```
# In app/admin/users.rb
action_item only: [:show] do
  link_to('Download File', download_admin_user_path(resource)) if resource.upload_file.present?
end

member_action :download, method: :get do
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  send_file user.upload_file
end
```

or, my preference, just leverage the RESTful show action in `upload_file.rb`

```
# In app/admin/users.rb
action_item only: [:show] do
  # NOTE: remove period from file extension
  file_ext = resource.upload_file.file_extension.gsub('.', '')
  link_to('Download File', download_admin_upload_file_path(resource.upload_file, format: file_ext)) if resource.upload_file.present?
end

# In app/admin/upload_files.rb
controller do    
  def show
    if params[:format] == 'txt' # example of a known mimetype, e.g. text file
      send_data resource.path, type: 'text/plain'
    elsif params[:format] == resource.file_extension # example of unknown mimetype
      send_file resource.path
    # let ActiveAdmin perform default behavior
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

cite: http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html

Comment: What I found with rails 6.0.3.7 is that ONLY the controller approach works; the custom member action failed for me. the log shows that the file was "sent" but no file was downloaded. Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132864/send-file-send-data-not-sending-file-for-downloading) and similar issues but no proposed solutions  worked for me except this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the complete code that you are using but that should work -

**routes.rb** -

```
resources :users do
    collection do
      get :upload_file
    end
  end
```

**controller** -

```
 def upload_file
    send_file @user.upload_file.path, :type => 'application/pdf', :filename =>  @user.permalink
  end
```

**View** -

```
 <%= link_to 'Download file', upload_file_users_path(@user) %>
```

Comment: does this method work with activeAdmin interface? i have done ua way but i get this error [No route matches {:action=>"upload_file", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}]

Comment: change `routes.rb` file with my latest updated post above and then run. Also check your routes for upload file by running `rake routes` if you get error in routing paths.

Comment: see the view if you not noted, its now `upload_file_users_path(@user)` and not `upload_file_user_path(@user)`. Change it and check the result. Again don't forget to check your path in routes if you still get routing errors.

Comment: i was forced to restart my computer, so that error stopped but i got i new one [undefined method `upload_file_user_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActionItem]

Comment: that worked, but it says [You need to sign in or sign up before continuing] and checking my url http://localhost:3000/admin/users/1, changes to http://localhost:3000/users/upload_file.1. i think this method locks itself to the users and not accessible to the adminpanel, activeadmin. am i right?