# send_file/send_data not sending file for downloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm using rails 3.2.22.4 and ruby 2.2.4. i'm testing send_file feature. I get "file sent" in server logs but i cant see it is getting downloaded in browser. Save button click will call this action.

```
def save_trunk_logs
  device_id = params['device_id']
  trunk_name = params['trunk_name'] ||= "test"
  data =""
  file = "#{trunk_name}.txt"
  trunk_logs = TrunkStatusLog.select([:LogType, :LogMessage, :EpochLoggedAtTime]).where(DeviceID: device_id)
  File.open(file, "w+") do |aFile|
    aFile.write("Trunk Name : #{trunk_name}\n")
    aFile.write("*"*100)
    aFile.write("\n")
    aFile.write("Time Stamp"+"\t"+"Log Message\n")
    trunk_logs.each do |msg|
      data =format_log_messages msg
      aFile.write("#{data}\n")
    end
  end
  send_file file, :type => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

This action is called by a button_to click event.

```
$("input[value='Download']").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/dm/trunk_test_tools/save_trunk_logs?device_id="+selectedTrunkDeviceId+"&trunk_name="+selectedTrunkDeviceName,
       }
    })
});
```

every time i hit download button 2 calls are made. server side log is pasted below

```
Started POST "/X/Y/save_trunk_logs?device_id=9&trunk_name=SIP_1" for      10.198.2.208 at 2016-10-24 12:58:58 +0530
Processing by ABCController#save_trunk_logs as */*
Parameters: {"device_id"=>"9", "trunk_name"=>"SIP_1"}
Sent file SIP_1.txt (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 98.0ms (ActiveRecord: 62.0ms)

Started POST "/X/Y/save_trunk_logs" for 10.198.2.208 at 2016-10-24 12:58:59 +0530
Processing by TrunkTestToolsController#save_trunk_logs as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3HSxduOUwccwo="}
sent file test.txt (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17.0ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

I dont understand why second call is made and from where it is being made. in the first server call it says file is sent but does not download. In second call file is sent as well as downloaded. but it is of no use. parameters not not correct. authenticity token i am not sending as parameter.(actual data queries are skipped.)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe not a solution but can you try this `send_file( file, :filename => 'my_file.txt'  )` ?

Comment: I just copied your code and it works. Maybe there's something you're not putting in here?

Comment: @lcguida i have tried the same code in my application as well(test application) and it works. i have modified the question and please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why this method is working. But serves my purpose.

```
$("#btn_id").on('click', function () {
    window.location = ypur api url;
});
```

Thanks,

Ajith